# Cant create new route on Mailgun. Get "Routes quota (0) is exceeded"

Tags: routes, mailgun, creation, quota

I'm trying to create new route on Mailgun.

Here's my code:

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-MyApiKeyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' https://api.mailgun.net/v3/routes -F priority=0 -F 'description=Tout pour le domaine mg.domain.tld' -F 'expression=match_recipient(".*@mg.domain.tld")' -F 'action=forward("firstname.lastname@email.com")' -F 'action=stop()'
```

I tried several time with few modifications, but I always get the same result.

```
{
  "message": "Routes quota (0) is exceeded"
}
```

How many routes can be created ?
If there an issue with my code ?

Thank for your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

You may be using a flex plan, which does not support inbound email routing. The account differences can be found here: https://www.mailgun.com/pricing/